# Android Equivalent of a Swift Dictionary?

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I am new to coding for Android and currently trying to convert over code from Swift.

I've searched and been unable to find a good solution for grouping a list of names by the first letter. In Swift this can be done with a key value pair using the first letter as the key in the form of a dictionary.

As far as the data goes, the list is always changing because it comes from an API so the code must be dynamic to adjust accordingly.

Example Data: Batman, Batgirl, Captain America, Captain Marvel, Iceman, Iron Man, Iron Patriot, Thor

Desired output:

B: Batman, Batgirl
C: Captain America, Captain Marvel
I: Iceman, Iron Man, Iron Patriot
T: Thor

So far I have tried looping through the list and grabbing the first character using charAt(), but then I haven't been able to assign the names to the corresponding letter.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You look for HashMap perhaps.

Comment: `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` might help. Don't forget to initialize null items

Answer (score 0):

This might be a common [`java.util.Dictionary<K, V>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Dictionary)... but there it reads:

> NOTE: This class is obsolete. New implementations should implement the Map interface, rather than extending this class.

Therefore you're looking for [`java.util.Map`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map), as suggested in the documentation.

Comment: `Dictionary` hasn't been used in 25 years. From the link: "**NOTE: This class is obsolete.**"

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the `Map` interface. Note that the *shape* of data returned from an API normally doesn't change, merely the values, so the usual practice is to write a Java class modeling the JSON response and then use Gson (on Android or server) or Jackson (on server) to automatically map it.